# Syntax error: Expected ")" but got identifier "ciclos" at [62:23]

Tags: google-bigquery

I try to do a 2 time conversion something like this:

```
select TIME_DIFF(TIME ciclos.hora_inicio, TIME ciclos.hora_fin, MINUTE) as diferencia from 
  (select 
     split(split(document_name, '/ciclos/')[OFFSET(1)], '/eventos/')[OFFSET(0)] as id_ciclo, 
     REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.codigo'), '"', '') as codigo, 
     REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.hora_fin'), '"', '') as hora_fin,  
     REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.hora_inicio'), '"', '') as hora_inicio,  
   from `fleetpas-34c3d.eventos.flet_raw_changelog`
   where document_id = 'XPr9cyA9yn3U51rvRANQ'
  ) as ciclos
```

https://roboquery.com/app/syntax-time-diff-function-bigquery

Comment: what is position [62:23] in your query?

Comment: [62:23] select TIME_DIFF(TIME ciclos.hora_inicio, TIME ciclos.hora_fin, MINUTE)  as direncia from

Comment: this way it worked ok: select TIME_DIFF(TIME '06:45:18', TIME '06:39:57', MINUTE) as diferencia from

Comment: Ignoring your error for now, please also be careful about your the order in the `TIME_DIFF()` function.  `TIME_DIFF(a,b,interval)` is b-a.  The way your query is written, I'm assuming you have it backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below instead (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
TIME_DIFF(PARSE_TIME('%T', ciclos.hora_inicio), PARSE_TIME('%T', ciclos.hora_fin), MINUTE)
```

note: assuming (per your comments) format of hora_inicio and hora_fin is like '06:45:18'

Comment: TIME_DIFF(CAST(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(evento.data, '$.hora_fin'), '"', '') AS TIME),CAST(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(evento.data, '$.hora_inicio'), '"', '') AS TIME),   MINUTE) as diferencia